# convert coordinates to json for upload to database

Tags: php, ios, mysql, json, core-location

I am trying to convert a user's location to json before i can insert it into mysql database with php, can anyone help? I am very new at this, my code is below:

Project detail: I am trying to create code that will:

- on first launch create a user ID
- collect the location of the device
- convert the user id and longitude/latitude into Json
- print the Json in the Label "Label1"
- then send the json to a mysql database

Right now, no coordinates or user ID are appearing on my label, could anyone help?

This is my ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
self.mapView.delegate = self;

locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[locationManager setDelegate:self];
[locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
[locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];

[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
NSLog(@" lat: %f",locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude);
NSLog(@" lon: %f",locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude);

//   Request use on iOS 8
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1) {
    [self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
} else {
    [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
}


if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"])
{
    //App has previously launched
}
else
{
    //First launch
    NSString *identifierString = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:identifierString forKey:@"uuidKey"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

NSURL *jsonFileUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://random.name/service.php"];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:jsonFileUrl];
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];

}

#pragma mark NSURLConnectionDataProtocol Methods

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
_downloadedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
[_downloadedData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSMutableArray *_locations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// Parse the JSON that came in
NSError *error;
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_downloadedData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
// Loop through Json objects, create question objects and add them to our questions array
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.count; i++)
{
    NSDictionary *jsonElement = jsonArray[i];
    MKPointAnnotation* marker = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];

    marker.title = jsonElement[@"Name"];
    marker.subtitle = jsonElement[@"Address"];
    coordinate.latitude = [jsonElement [@"Latitude"] doubleValue];
    coordinate.longitude = [jsonElement [@"Longitude"] doubleValue];

    marker.coordinate = coordinate;
    // Add this question to the locations array
    [_locations addObject:marker];

    NSDictionary* info = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          [jsonElement objectForKey:@"Name"], @"uuidKey",
                          [jsonElement objectForKey:@"Latitude"], @" lat: %f",
                          [jsonElement objectForKey:@"Longitude"], @"lon: %f",
                          nil];

    //convert object to data
    NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:info
                                                       options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                         error:&error];

    //print out the data contents
    Label1.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData
                                             encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    }
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status {
if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse) {
    [self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
}
}
```

Comment: What is the result in JsonArray & info

Comment: JsonArray takes each entry from the database, then each entry is checked with jsonelements to find the values name, latitude, etc and then displayed on the map.

Comment: for `NSDictionary* info` I want the uuidkey, lat and lon to be changed to json and pasted on `Label1`

Comment: I am asking JsonArray result and info dictinary result give sample once print info

Comment: right now, the code is posting the jsonArray result on the map as an annotation, nothing is appearing on the label representing info

Comment: Once print NSDictionary* info tel me what is the reslut

Comment: nothing just this "{"

Comment: The NSDictionary* info is empty ! you are converting empty dictionary to JSON object and show to label ! it's show empty ! just check out why it is empty

Comment: i am trying to create nsdictionary and assign uuid, lat and lon to it before turning it to json, can you tell me how to turn those values into json?

Comment: Once Print jsonArray what is the output show me